# GNU scheme outport

Tags: scheme, gnu

I want to save the result of any programming run on GNU/scheme. In order to do this I prepared the following test file(please see below). I was thinking that by running this, a scm file which just contains the word "01234" would be saved in the relevant directory under the name "testfile" but I couldn't find any file although GNU scheme says "done" after running this program. Could anybody kindly tell me what is wrong with this? I am running GNU scheme on windows (downloaded from; http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/  "I installed windows binary"
) and the directory on my pc where i think the file will be saved is;
C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme

Below is the content of the test program

```
(define outport (open-output-file "testfile"))  
(display "abcde" outport)  
(newline outport)  
(display "01234" outport)  
(newline outport)  
(close-output-port outport)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me (with GNU Guile Scheme). File is created in the current directory, not necessarily the installation directory. Try searching for the file in Explorer, starting from C:\

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to serach the file under C: but I could not find it...Anyway, thanks.

Comment: oh, I just could find it. It was in a hidden folder. Thank you very much for your help!!!!

Comment: The file will be called `testfile`, *not* `testfile.scm`, in case you searched for the latter. Otherwise, try to launch the program from a DOS box. The file should be in the current directory then.

Answer (score 2):

Uselpa's explanation is spot on.

The manual has the following to say:

> 15.2 Working Directory
>
> When MIT/GNU Scheme is started, the current working directory (or simply, 
>   working directory) is initialized in an operating-system
>   dependent manner; usually, it is the directory in which Scheme was
>   invoked. The working directory can be determined from within Scheme by
>   calling the pwd procedure, and changed by calling the cd procedure.
>   Each REP loop has its own working directory, and inferior REP loops
>   initialize their working directory from the value in effect in their
>   superior at the time they are created.

This means that you can use

```
(pwd)
```

in the Scheme repl to see where your file is saved.

Comment: Thank you very much. By typing (pwd) it returned C:\\program files (x86)\\mit-gnu scheme\\  so I think I am looking into a right directory but there is no output file which should be there... But anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: I just could find the file in a folder which had been hidden. Thank you!!